# Please find the expectation

Tags: statistics

Consider the i.i.d. sequence
$X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5, X_6$
where each $X_i$ is one of the four symbols $\{a, t, g, c\}$. Further suppose
that
$\mathbb{P}(X_1 = a) = 0.1,\ \mathbb{P}(X_1 = t) = 0.2,\ P(X_1 = g) = 0.3$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_1 = c) = 0.4$.
Let $Z$ denote the random variable that counts the number of times
that the subsequence $cat$ occurs (i.e. the letters $c$, $a$ and $t$ occur consecutively
and in the correct order) in the above sequence. Find $\mathbb{E}(Z)$.

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck? Please complete your question with such information. (And the answer is 0.032.)

Comment: @did:I could not understand how to start and "cat" words is quite cofusing

Comment: Which similar, simpler, problems can you solve? For example, what is the mean number of times `a` appears in the very same sequence?

Comment: Are your probabilities $\mathbb{P}(X_i = a) = 0.1$ and similar?  That is, the probability applies to all six positions?

Comment: Too late... $ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that uses the linearity of expectation is slick and general. The following is a lower level approach that would get unpleasant in "larger" situations.

Let $W$ be the number of occurrences of the word 'cat.' We have $W=0$, $W=1$, or $W=2$.  Then by the definition of expectation, 
$$E(W)=(0)\Pr(W=0)+(1)\Pr(W=1)+(2)\Pr(W=2).\tag{$1$}$$
We find the various probabilities. Of course, if we find $\Pr(W=1)$ and $\Pr(W=2)$, then finding $\Pr(W=0)$ will be easy. And anyway we don't even need $\Pr(W=0)$, since in Formula $(1)$ it gets multiplied by $0$. The probability that $W=2$ is $(0.4)(0.1)(0.2)(0.4)(0.1)(0.2)$.

The probability that $W=1$ is trickier. The probability that we have 'cat' in positions $1$, $2$, and $3$ is $(0.4)(0.1)(0.2)$. The same is true for positions $2$, $3$, and $4$, also $3$, $4$, and $5$, also $4$, $5$, and $6$. Add these probabilities. We get $(4)((0.4)(0.1)(0.2)$. However, this counts **twice** the probability of 'catcat' and we want to count it **zero** times. So the probability that $W=1$ is equal to $1$ is
$$4(0.4)(0.1)(0.2)-2(0.4)(0.1)(0.2)(0.4)(0.1)(0.2).$$
Now calculate, using Formula $(1)$. Observe the cancellation, which tells us that we are probably missing a better and simpler solution, as indeed we are.

Answer (score 1):

To form cat you need c followed by a , followed by t.  The probability of getting that exact sequence is p=0.4* 0.1*0.2  But with six random variables there are several distinct ways this can happen namely 1) X1, X2 and X3 2) X2, X3 and X4, 3) X3, X4 and X5 and 4) X4, X5 and X6.  So there are 4 distinct ways that three consecutive variables can spell cat in order.  Hence you multiply p by 4.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Z_i$ be a variable that is $1$ if the string $X_{i-1}X_{i}X_{i+1}$ is $cat$, and $0$ otherwise.

Now $Z = Z_2+Z_3+Z_4+Z_5$.

Take expectations on both sides, use linearity of expectations, and note that each of these four $Z_i$'s is 0.4*0.1*0.2.

Comment: Yes, and there was also one more typo ($Z_i$ should be 1 if the condition is met). Thanks vanguard2k for fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow up to Wonder's answer: if you want to compute all the probabilities then you can proceed as follows.

The only possibilities are $Z = 0$, $Z = 1$ or $Z = 2$.

Starting with $Z=2$, this will only happen if you get "cat" twice; thus,

\begin{equation}
P(Z=2) = P(X_1=c)P(X_2=a)P(X_3=t)P(X_4=c)P(X_2=a)P(X_3=t) = p^2,
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}
p = P(X_1=c)P(X_2=a)P(X_3=t) = 0.4\times0.1\times0.2 = 0.008
\end{equation}

For $Z=1$ we have 4 possibilities (as the $Z_i$ in Wonder's answer), but we must exclude the possibility of having 2 cats in a row. So

\begin{equation}
P(Z=1) = 2p + 2p(1-p) = 4p - 2p^2
\end{equation}

Finally,

\begin{equation}
P(Z=0) = 1-P(Z=1)-P(Z=2)
\end{equation}

The following 3 lines of code instantaneously simulate this in Mathematica, in case you are interested.

```
n=100000;
data = Map[StringJoin,RandomChoice[{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4} -> 
       {"a", "t", "g","c"}, {n,6}]];
z = Map[Length@StringCases[#, "cat"] &, data];
```

Then either use Histogram[z] to see a plot or (1.0/n)Map[Count[z, #] &, {0, 1, 2}] to get the probabilities themselves.